# How to reset JQueryUI Resizable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using JqueryUI to create draggable and resizable elements to generate html page. When I'm saving the html content, all classes and style are kept in my html page (like ui-wrapper and ui-resizable-handle).

When I'm loading the html page, I want to init resizable on images. But there are already ui-wrapper parent and ui-handles around this img tag, and I can't use resizable event. If I reinit resizable() on my image, it generates an other wrapper and handles.

Example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Alex197/6ebn4jsa/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.img').each(function(){
   $(this).resizable();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 450px; height: 300px; top: 10px; left: 10px; margin: 0px; z-index: 10;">
   <img id="f93wmxm" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img context-menu-one" style="margin: 0px; resize: none; position: static; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 300px; width: 450px;">
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

How could I reinit resizable event on my image without duplicate wrapper and handles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use
$(this).resizable("destroy");

Comment: Hi, I already tried but I got this error: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'".